# Java new long(0)

Tags: java

In my class I have this parameter:

```
public Long label_id ;
```

When I try to evaluate the value from label_id which is 0

```
if(item.label_id == new Long(0)) {
    Doesn't enter here
} else {
    Enters here
}
```

It is supposed to enter the condition since both are zero but it enters the else condition.  I even tried debugging the code:

```
label_id    Long  (id=142)  
    value 0
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Use `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: `item.label_id == new Long(0)` compares object reference, not a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to improve upon the answers by @Rocket and @ParkerHalo to explain why the `new Long(0)` doesn't work.

So the problem with the if line of code is that the `new Long(0)` creates an object of class `Long`, however you aren't compairing classes, want you are comparing are [primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Primitive types have no methods and are basally a set amount of memory dedicated to storing a number (Read the comments). They were created with C and most (if not all) made their way into Java. However the `Long` Class has various methods to make working with longs easier in some cases.

You cannot compare them in this way because the `new Long(0)` returns a reference to a class, not a primitive type.

The quickest way to get your code up and running is to do as @ParkerHalo suggested and compare the value returned to a primitive long with the value of Zero. So if you wanted to see if it was Zero you would use:

`if(item.label_id.longValue() == 0L) {`

And you can replace the `0` with other values, as long as you keep the `L` for longs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ParkerHalo But at the same time they store the data as numbers. So you can do addition and subtraction with chars, because they are just numbers attributed to an ASCII mapping table. And a boolean is just a 1 or a 0. I will add a note to look at these comments.

Answer (score 10):

You should extract the value of `label_id` first and then compare it:

```
if(item.label_id.longValue() == 0L)
```

Comment: This one worked but I have to remove the L.  Code is item.label_id.longValue() == 0

Answer (score 6):

You are using an object comparison. and with new ... you generate a new object. the both objects are not the same...
You can use new Long(0).equals(...)

Answer (score 2):

The == operator in Java checks for object equality. With `new Long(0)` you explicitly create a new object that will never have the same identity as any other Long.

Use the `equals` method, but beware of NullPointerExceptions`.

```
if(item.label_id.equals(new Long(0))) {

} else {

}
```

You could also try to rely on the cache, but I wouldn't do that

```
if(item.label_id == Long.valueOf(0)) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
item.label_id.longValue() == new Long(0).longValue()
```

or

```
item.label_id.equals(new Long(0))
```

Otherwise you compare memory adresses / pointers